# Measure retweets and top influencer

Tags: twitter

According to [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1), it returns up to 100 of the first retweets of a given tweet.

1. What is the best way to measure number of retweets, when the amount
   is higher than 100?
2. What is the best way to find top influencer of my tweet (Person, who retweeted my tweet, and he has the highest number of retweets)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answers:

1. Twitter API [Get Status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) provide amount of retweets: **"retweet_count"**
   If you want to get all retweets you should periodically query Twitter to get [retweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3aid).

   **Note:** In spite, Twitter API allows to return up to 100 retweets, it usually return only latest retweets during last random timing frame.
2. New style retweets track only first level. Example:

   **@bob**: My Awesome application http://bit.ly/1234

   **@alice**: RT: @bob My Awesome application http://bit.ly/1234

   But if **@eve** RT **@alice** retweet, the message will be similar to alice's and she won't be mentioned in it.

   **@eve**: RT: @bob My Awesome application http://bit.ly/1234

The old style was (not in use anymore):  *RT: @alice: RT: @bob My Awesome application http://bit.ly/1234*

**Important!**
There is some Twitter API limit https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1. OAuth-enabled application could initiate 350 GET-based requests per hour per access token.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with the Instagram API, the method suggested above will work really well.

I you do not want to work with the API, many free social media tools are available that will do this stuff for you. Search "twitter analytics tools" and you will find an array of options. Crowdbabble has a free trial that will let you track your retweets and the top influencers who follow you -- you can sort your followers in a table by the number of followers they have.